# How to get length of variables in wstringstream

Tags: c++

Is there any way to measure the length of each variable printed using `wstringstream`?

I mean `x: 4`, `wstring: 11`, `hwnd: 10`

For `example`:

```
int main()
{
    int x              =  1000;
    std::wstring A     =  L"Hello World";
    HWND hwnd          =  L"0x000103FC";
    
    std::wstringstream ss;
    ss << L"x: "            << x
       << L", wstring: "     << A
       << L", hwnd: "        << hwnd;
       
    return 0;
}
```

I'm asking for a way that doesn't involve converting all data types to string and calculating it with `.length()`.

Comment: It should be possible to write a `streambuf` implementation that discards all output, and only counts the number of characters sent to it. None such exists in the standard library, to my knowledge; if you need one, you'd have to roll your own.

Comment: If you call `ss.tellp()` before and after outputting each variable, the difference should tell you how many characters were produced while formatting that variable. An example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/tellp) demonstrates this.

Comment: That `HWND` line almost certainly doesn't do what you think it does. You're taking a constant character array which happens to resemble a hex number, then taking a reference to that array. `hwnd` is a pointer to the character array, reinterpreted as a window handle.